# Resize form in Android depending on the size of the devices

Tags: java, android, xml, forms, android-layout

I made this form which, on my emulator (Google Pixel c), looks like in the picture below:

[image]

Then I tried the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab and a white bar appeared:

[image]

How can I fix it? This is my xml code of the form:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/MyDialog"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_form"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:text="OK">

</Button>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_11sdp"
    android:text="Abilitare la palette di colori?" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Inserisci l'eta'">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myCheckBox">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:text="Maschio" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:text="Femmina" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I used the SDP library to adapt it to every screen resolution. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Change width and height of `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`

Comment: @Nidheesh nothing changed.

Comment: I guess your problem is giving the parent RelativeLayout a fixed height. Try giving it a wrap_content. Also for the width and height of the child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as suggested by @vidulaJ

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/MyDialog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_24sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:text="OK">

</Button>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_11sdp"
    android:text="Abilitare la palette di colori?" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Inserisci l'eta'">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myCheckBox">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:text="Maschio" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:text="Femmina" />
</RadioGroup>
```